# Работа с регулярными выражениями PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст, нужно все URL выделить красным и добавить перед ними 
`<ahref="URL"URL</a>`, а если там есть человекочитаемая, то `<ahref="URL"URL;человекочитаемая</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще не понял, что значит "человекочитаемая"

```
$string = 'текст со ссылками www.demo.com и тут еще одна ссылка ftp://com.ru/?awdaw=dawdw%20 и еще https://demo.com.ru/ теперь хватит';
$pattern = '/((https?|ftp):\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\S]*)*\/?/i';
$replacement = '<a href="$0">$0</a>';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

[image: Картинка]

Comment: Человекочитаемая - наверное имеется ввиду, когда ссылка не с get-параметрами, а вида /products/categories/1